# Postgresql - Return additional columns based on the selection criteria of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm new to postgresql so I don't even know if I'm on the right track. This is what I want the results to look like:
            Web    Web        Other  Other        Dist    Dist
    Week        Qty    Sales       Qty   Sales        Qty     Sales

```
8/18/2014   1120   74436.60    1068   38516.44   28034   244504.64
8/4/2014    653    39850.225  34726  476872.65    7962   255772.98
7/28/2014   760    40740.295  28009  950602.16    3222   145952.57
7/21/2014   913     48877.47  34082 1286582.67    6332   247922.63
7/14/2014   977     79177.73  22147  828173.65   21542   286437.43
7/7/2014    918     58949.72  49302 1253558.70    4129   211738.23
```

The records are summarized by week, and are created from 1 column and one calculated column: 1. Order Quantity 2. Order Quantity * Unit Price. I used case statements to separate them into different columns based on the sale type or Customer type. (Sale type INT = Web, sale type Not INT = Other, customer type DIST = Dist)

The code I used is listed below.

```
SELECT 
cast(date_trunc('week', cohead_orderdate) AS date) AS week, 

-- Web Quantity Sold
CASE WHEN saletype_code = 'INT' THEN
SUM(invcitem_billed) 
END AS web_qty, 

-- Web $ Sales
CASE WHEN saletype_code = 'INT' THEN
SUM(invcitem_billed * invcitem_price)
END AS web_sales,

-- All Other Quantities Sold (phone, fax, email, etc.)
CASE WHEN saletype_code != 'INT' THEN
SUM(invcitem_billed) 
END AS other_qty, 

-- All Other $ Sales (phone, fax, email, etc.)
CASE WHEN saletype_code != 'INT' THEN
SUM(invcitem_billed * invcitem_price)
END AS other_sales,

-- Dist Quantities Sold 
CASE WHEN custtype_code = 'DIST' THEN
SUM(invcitem_billed) 
END AS dist_qty, 

-- Dist Other $ Sales
CASE WHEN custtype_code = 'DIST'  THEN
SUM(invcitem_billed * invcitem_price)
END AS dist_sales

FROM cohead ordhdr
LEFT JOIN saletype ON (cohead_saletype_id = saletype_id) 
LEFT JOIN custinfo ON (cohead_cust_id = cust_id)
LEFT JOIN custtype ON (cust_custtype_id = custtype_id)
JOIN invchead invhdr ON ordhdr.cohead_number = invhdr.invchead_ordernumber
JOIN invcitem invdtl ON invhdr.invchead_id = invdtl.invcitem_invchead_id
WHERE (cohead_status != 'X')
AND (cohead_orderdate >= <? value('startDate') ?>) 
AND (cohead_orderdate <= <? value('endDate') ?>)
GROUP BY week,
saletype_code,
custtype_code

ORDER BY week DESC;
```

The problem is it wants me to include the Sale type and the Customer type that I'm using for my selection criteria in a GROUP BY clause which obviously creates several groupings and therefore there are several records for each week.

```
Week       Web         Web      Other      Other      Dist  Dist
           Qty        Sales      Qty       Sales      Qty    Sales
8/4/2014      0           0       29      922.65        29  922.65
8/4/2014      0           0      575           0         0          0
8/4/2014      0           0      208    12098.16         0          0
8/4/2014      0           0       20      630.00         0          0
8/4/2014      0           0      858    34892.97       858   34892.97
8/4/2014      0           0      574    29017.78         0          0
8/4/2014    155    10605.00        0           0         0          0
7/28/2014     0           0      546           0         0          0
7/28/2014     0           0      579    29443.98         0          0
7/28/2014     0           0     1645    68356.15      1645   68356.15
7/28/2014     0           0      888    45794.48         0          0
7/28/2014   346    23638.16        0           0         0          0
7/21/2014     0           0       14      827.00         0          0
7/21/2014     0           0      106           0       106          0
7/21/2014     0           0      227      348.10         0          0
7/21/2014     0           0      361    22503.91         0          0
7/21/2014     0           0     3050   119407.24      3050  119407.24
7/21/2014     0           0      448    27735.26         0          0
7/21/2014   288    17139.08        0           0         0          0
7/21/2014     0           0       20      704.00         0          0
7/21/2014     0           0        3           0         0          0
```

This is my first question I've submitted here so I hope I've submitted enough (but not too much) information. I'll appreciate any help/advice you can give. 
Thanx!!!

Comment: I noticed after I posted that the data examples aren't formatted. How do I format them so they display correctly here?

Comment: Use `<pre>...</pre>` tags to format that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Clodoaldo Neto screwed up your formatting. You may want to put it back.

Comment: @mawburn I and a_horse were editing at the same time and I didn't see his formatting. If you think that one is better then do it yourself

Answer (score 0):

In instead of

```
CASE WHEN saletype_code = 'INT' THEN
SUM(invcitem_billed) 
END AS web_qty,
```

do

```
sum(
    CASE
        WHEN saletype_code = 'INT' THEN invcitem_billed
    END
) AS web_qty,
```